# Is there any collapsable with resize menu plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

Lets take a look at google services menu:

[image]

There is that `More` pop up menu. but when we resize page all that top menu line does nothing - its width stays constant:

[image]

Same thing happens when we enlarge page width:

[image]

So I wonder if there is any jQuery plugin for greation of smart top bar menus that would add items to `More` when needed and return items from `More` to main menu when resulution allows that.

Is there any such plugin for jQuery?

Comment: Don't know if there is already, you can write your own. Shouldn't be that hard :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, something like [this](http://roi.webfactional.com/img/so/overflowmenutest.htm)?

Comment: Grate one! - small yet effective (and with a little [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646533/why-overflowing-menu-is-working-bad-when-there-are-0-items-in-visible-original-u) ) 
BTW: I loved this more than [Bootstrap Navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar)